# How to send SMS from PHP application using Huawei e8372 Wingle

Tags: php, com, sms, huawei-mobile-services

I have a Huawei E8372 LTE Wingle, I want to connect to this device using PHP code to send SMS programmatically. I have tried to find how to connect it.

I am using this device on Windows 10 64-bit operating system.

Comment: What have you tried? Where is your code, and what libraries are you leveraging?

Comment: I have tried: https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/866473/How-to-send-sms-using-dongle-in-php but according to the publisher he is also facing error- he is trying with COM13 which is the problem to him...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask What specific problem do you have when trying to reproduce this project? No one wants to design a program for you. This site works best when you have a specific problem you need help with. You need to work from the known to the unknown, solving problems as you go. Get a basic framework going, and move in testable increments. If you need help with a specific problem, then ask here.

Comment: @jdv thanks for replay. I have a very simple question: i need to send sms message from my php page via connected E8372 Huawei winble device? can we send sms from this device with php ?

Comment: I don't know. Maybe? Have you tried anything? What were the results? There are so many steps that you have to get right to "send an SMS from PHP from a device XYZ" that it is literally unanswerable.

Comment: in fact i have no idea how to send sms from this device but as much as i know i think i will need to connect to this device via COM port. but in windows 10 i am not able to find the COM Port for this device?

Comment: It sounds like you need to start at the beginning: find a way to get some sort of serial connection to a phone from Windows. I'd start there. This is what I mean about working in a stepwise manner.

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick update for everyone still strugling. E8372 works in Hilink mode by default.

1. Only the latest version of usb_modeswitch (check with `usb_modeswitch -e`, I have 2.5.2) can switch it back to ttyUSB mode. So update it first if you're on an older version.
2. Then download the new usb-modeswitch-data package from https://www.draisberghof.de/usb_modeswitch/ (not available in raspberry repositories yet). Unpack it, and run `gen-rules.tcl` to install (might require to do `apt install tcl` first).

Voila. Now you have /dev/ttyUSB*